# How to share logger instance among Flask app and other classes

Tags: python, logging, flask

I have a python app where the main class is a Flask app, and when I receive a HTTP request I launch methods from other classes. I want to share the logger and apparently it should be very easy but I can't make it work.

Here is my code for the main class:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, make_response, request
from SGRuntime import SGRuntime
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

app = Flask(__name__)
sgRuntime = SGRuntime()

@app.route('/sg/api/v2.0/init', methods=['GET'])
def init_service():
    app.logger.info('Request: Init service')
    return sgRuntime.start()


@app.route('/sg/api/v2.0/stop', methods=['GET'])
def stop_service():
    app.logger.info('Request: Stop service')
    return sgRuntime.stop()


@app.route('/sg/api/v2.0/restart', methods=['GET'])
def restart_service():
    app.logger.info('Request: Restart service')
    return sgRuntime.restart()


@app.route('/sg/api/v2.0/alive', methods=['GET'])
def alive():
    if sgRuntime.running == True:
        return sgRuntime.get_stat()
    else:
        return "Service not running"

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('./SGLog.log', when='midnight', interval=1)
    handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    fileFormatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(fileFormatter)
    app.logger.addHandler(handler)
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the code for my SGRuntime.py where I would like to use the same logger:

```
import serial
import logging

class SGRuntime():

CONFIG_FILE_PATH = "config.cfg"
running = False
configuration = {
    'port' : 'COM5',
    'baudrate' : '9600',
    'debug' : '0',
    'serverip' : '127.0.0.1',
    'serverport' : 8080
}    
protocol = None
startedSince = None

def __init__(self):
    self.running = False

def start(self):
    if self.running:

        return 'ERROR: ALREADY RUNNING'

    self.logger = logging.getLogger()
    self.logger.info('SGRuntime started')
```

The output of the logger is:

```
2016-01-21 16:20:28,137 INFO     Request: Init service
```

So I'm missing the logging from my SGRuntime class. Can you help me?

Thank you very much in advanced!

Comment: Instead of this, look at realtime logging and aggregation servers like [Sentry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentry), it is well worth (you can even aggregate logs and stacktraces from javascript, PHP, Java - you name it).

Comment: Maybe try using `self.logger = logging.getLoggerClass()`

Comment: @I'L'I I get this error: `TypeError: unbound method info() must be called with Logger instance as first argument (got str instance instead)`

Answer (score 3):

`logging.getlogger` creates a logger. So in SGRuntime you create a second logger. You want to import the `app.logger` instance from your package and use that for logging.

An easier way to do this could be confuguring the standard logger as described in [the logging how to: Logging from multiple modules](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/logging.html#logging-from-multiple-modules). You only have to call `logging.info('Your message')` and it will log when the logging level is INFO or DEBUG.

Answer (score 1):

`logging.getLogger()` returns the same instance of logger (against the logger name ) to test it you can make:

```
name = "myname"
logger = logging.getLogger(name)
for _ in range(100):
    assert logger is logging.getLogger(name)
```

So to have the same instance of a logger. Create a module called "mylogger" and import the logger instance created in this module anywhere where you will need a logger.